# Saving category as insert post

Tags: php, custom-taxonomy, categories

I'm having a problem with `$_POST` a category. I got something like that :

```
    // ADD THE FORM INPUT TO $new_post ARRAY
$new_post = array(
'post_title'    =>  $title,
'post_content'  =>  $description,
'post_category' =>  array($_POST['cat']),   // Usable for custom taxonomies too
'tags_input'    =>  array($tags),
'post_status'   =>  'draft',           // Choose: publish, preview, future, draft, etc.
'post_type' =>  'post'  //'post',page' or use a custom post type if you want to
);
```

And the code about taking category:

```
    <!-- post Category -->
<fieldset class="category">
    <label for="cat">Type:</label>
    <select name="cat" id="categories">
    <?php 
$categories = get_categories('tab_index=10&taxonomy=category&orderby=name&hide_empty=0&include=6,7,8,9,10');
foreach ($categories as $category) {
$option = '<option name ="'.$category->category_nicename.'" value="'.$category->category_nicename.'">';
$option .= $category->cat_name;
$option .= '</option>';
echo $option;
}
  ?>
 </select>
</fieldset>
```

However, It doesn't work If I use `wp dropdown categories` this works, but I need to have a `name` for the options.  `wp dropdown categories` doesn't provide the names itself. Is there anyone who knows what Am I missing here ?

Edited *

So after all It was simple enough to make it like that

```
 <!-- post Category -->
<fieldset class="category">
    <label for="cat">Type:</label>
    <select name="cat" id="categories">
    <?php 
$categories = get_categories('tab_index=10&taxonomy=category&orderby=name&hide_empty=0&include=6,7,8,9,10');
foreach ($categories as $category) {
$option = '<option name ="'.$category->category_nicename.'" value="'.$category->term_id.'">';
$option .= $category->cat_name;
$option .= '</option>';
echo $option;
}
  ?>
 </select>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: I think the array for post_category needs to be an array of integers, not a string, and that's what you are getting from the $_POST['cat'] the way you have it written.  Change the value in the option to the category id instead.

Comment: @leromt I concur, that seems like the likely reason, might make sense as an answer :)

Comment: So should I just do $_POST['categories'] ? I believe I've tried that, but.. let's see one more time xD So yea, as I thought, I've tried that. And .. It is indeed saving a category, but not the selected one.. It saves `no category` so the default one... ;(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array for post_category needs to be an array of integers, not a string, and that's what you are getting from the $_POST['cat'] the way you have it written. Change the value in the option to the category id instead.

Comment: So should I just do $_POST['categories'] ? I believe I've tried that, but.. let's see one more time xD So yea, as I thought, I've tried that. And .. It is indeed saving a category, but not the selected one.. It saves `no category` so the default one... ;(

Comment: Ok, thanks I guess I had to make It on fresh mind ;) Yea, changing value to category id was just enough ;) thx